# How to endorse that a string is a version of something or not?

Tags: python, string

*FYI, It is not duplicate please remove this tag.*

I have tried `packaging.version.Version` it does not work on `1.0.2h` and `192.168.0.3`.

**Question**

I am getting versions of different libraries/binaries in a list. And this list includes some garbage values of version along with correct one. I want to write a python code that can separate correct ones from the version list.

Please suggest a logic or python library which can do the following

**Psuedo Code**

```py
Correct_verList = []

verList = ['2.6.36', '1.2.dfgdf', '1.sdfsdgsdsf', '3.0/0+3*/1,-/0/0,//O*K1', 'so.802', '5.0(side)', '6.2*20hm' , '192.168.0.222', '1.33', '0.97a', '1.0.2h', '2.4.2b3']

#Psuedo Code
for ver in verList: 
    if ver is the correct version:
         Correct_verList.append(ver)

print(Correct_verList)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Correct_verList = [1.33, 0.97a, 2.6.36, 1.0.2h, 2.4.2b3]
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh dear, it is different, as it is to find that if a string is version or not. and u suggested the version comparison.

Comment: If you look at the answer again `version.Version("1.3.xy123")` checks if a string is a valid version or not

Comment: `packaging.version.Version` doesn't seem to allow `1.0.2h`.

Comment: `packaging.version.Version` says `192.168.0.12` is a version, in actual, it is not a version.

Comment: Can't add an answer because of the duplicate but if your requirement is very specifically a number followed by a period followed by a combination of a letters and numbers optionally followed by a period and a combination of a letters and numbers you could solve it with a regular expression, something like `import re; result = [x for x in verList if re.fullmatch('\d+\.\w+(\.\w+)?', x)]`

Comment: @tfw this code is working for the given list. But it is too specific to the given list. It says `2.sfufdf`, `2.34e.34e` and `2.0.xxxdd` are versions but these are not. AND seems like I can't do anything regarding duplicate it is up to @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Your requirements are still not very clear to me, but maybe the expression `(\d+\.){1,2}\d+\w*` could solve it instead. Also, as the answerer suggested, I recommend you read up on the documentation for RegEx and experiment a bit with it, e.g. through [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). This link provide you documentation on python's regular expression.

This regular expression could do the job : `'(([0-9]+[.]){1,2}([0-9]*([0-9]|[a-z]){0,2}[0-9]+)'`

What you could do is to use the `findall()` method and test if the result is the same string you tested. The code would be like (I have not tested it) :

```
import re
Correct_verList = []

verList = ['2.6.36', '3.0/0+3*/1,-/0/0,//O*K1', 'so.802', '5.0(side)', '6.2*20hm' , '192.168.0.222', '1.33', '0.97a', '1.0.2h', '2.4.2b3']

for ver in verList:
    a=re.findall('(([0-9]+[.]){1,2}([0-9]*([0-9]|[a-z]){0,2}[0-9]+)',ver)
    if len(a)!=0:
       if a[0][0]==ver:
           Correct_verList.append(ver)
print(Correct_verList)
```

Comment: That regex won't match all of his requirements. Note that letters can be included in the last segment.

Comment: @tfw you are right, in last segment character is also possible

Comment: @Umair corrected. Is it matching your requirements?

Comment: @TUIlover there is an error in the code.

Comment: @Umair corrected. Still, you didn't explain why `192.168.0.12` shouldn't be in the list and my code does not exclude it

Comment: @TUIlover `192.168.0.12` is IP address. FYI, a version has maximum of three segments.

Comment: @Umair it should work now

Comment: Thanks @TUIlover, It is working. Can you please limit the characters appearing in the last segment to maximum 2. like `1.2.dfgdf` and `1.sdfsdgsdsf` are not versions.

Comment: @Umair You must use this regular expression : `'(([0-9]+[.]){1,2}([0-9]*([0-9]|[a-z]){0,2}[0-9]+)'` instead. I strongly recommend you to read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). The 7.2.1. section is short and is very useful, as regular expression are implemented in numerous languages in that way. If you think the question is answered, please up-vote the answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: @TUIlover I have done it finally....`RegEx` is an amazing library. Thanks, I will do it.